# Async await usage and overhead

Tags: c#, web, async-await, asp.net-web-api2

I have a web api 2 endpoint that talks to a service class.
The service class makes calls to Entity Framework (v6)

I have applied async await on the methods where im writing to the database, querying etc.. using SaveChangesAsync(), etc

My question is regarding the overhead..

the fact i have to apply async on the method signature in the service means i then have to apply await and async on any calling method in order to compile.

The fact im sprinkling async & await on methods calling the service method - does this result in a lot of extra overhead?  i.e.: my web api 2 endpoint now has async await applied to it as im calling this service method that has async & Task applied on it signature too.

The overhead i talk about is related to this article
https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/the-overhead-of-asyncawait-in-net-4.5/

Comment: The only way to know this is to measure it. Have a copy of the endpoint without async/await and do some load testing on it. Then do the same load testing on an endpoint with async/await... Also, the word is "I'm" not "im".

Comment: I think that article answers your question better than you are likely to get here.

Comment: Only you can determine how much the overhead is on your system, and whether or not that overhead is acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It results in some overhead, yes. Normally, it is not a concern. If you expect less than 1M tasks per second I would not think about this at all.

The biggest cost of using "async all the way" is that it infects a lot of code and impacts code quality. It can increase development cost and decrease software quality because it tends to be more error prone.

Comment: "Impacts code quality". Can you qualify this with an example?

Comment: @rolls well, it litters the code with async,await,Task. New exceptions are now possible, new failure modes, the call stack is messed up, profiling tools don't work, viral infection with async and surely 10 more productivity killers.

Comment: @rolls look at the await tag on Stack Overflow to see a nice buffet of new problems that async/await introduce. In my not so humble opinion the community at large is not aware enough of these issues. Also, many do not realize that async on the server adds zero benefits most of the time. Literally zero. In particular zero perf gain, but a slight perf loss. (Also stressing "most of the time" as opposed to always.)

Comment: If you are writing a large desktop application you would be crazy to not use async. Writing background threads and managing this yourself would cause more bugs than async. Deadlocks are an issue with threading regardless of if you use async, tasks or manual threads. Most the async issues are simply threading issues. Using async where it is not needed is silly, this I agree.

Comment: @rolls yes, async is great for desktop apps. Even there, Task.Run can often be used to have far less async pollution and get nice code structure in the GUI. Of course, many developers would not dare to use the "forbidden" API Task.Run. Not for good reasons but because they bought into the group think.; I disagree that most async issues are threading issues. There are many things that can go wrong in the new machinery.

Comment: What are other issues do you see?

Comment: The SynchronizationContext causes issues with deadlocks. You need ConfigureAwait(false) in libraries or else everything starts to run on the UI thread (silently). There are many ways you can now inadvertently start concurrency (e.g. cancelling a cancellation token can introduce concurrency). The whole reentrancy problem (https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/2454). All of these can be solved but it's added effort and risk. I want to be clear that async/await is a very useful technology. But it is overused. This is a cultural problem. @rolls